# Retrieve starting positions of the titles in the string

Tags: vb.net, string, indexof

I have a line of seven different titles that can consist of one or two words with at least 3 or 4 spaces between the title.

```
"  Company Name        Contact Name      Address            City    State    Zip    Phone"
```

I need to retrieve the position in the line where each title begins. I use indexOf:

```
pos1 = line.IndexOf("company", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

This method works fine but is not that efficient for retrieving positions since the line comes from text documents and there is a great variability, for example I might have something like this:

```
"  C0mpany Name        C0ntact Name      Address            NCity    St)te    Zip    Phone"
```

So the wording is not always exact. All I know is that there are 7 columns. What is the best way to retrieve 7 beginning positions of those columns programmatically?

Comment: You could split the string on substrings of three spaces, remove empty values and then trim each one.

Answer (score 0):

This works quite well

```
    Dim s As String
    Dim v As Object
    Dim tok As Object

    s = "  C0mpany Name        C0ntact Name      Address            NCity    St)te    Zip    Phone"
    v = Split(s, "  ")
    For Each tok In v
        If Len(Trim(tok)) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print(tok & vbTab & InStr(s, tok))
        End If
    Next
```

output:

```
C0mpany Name    3
C0ntact Name    23
Address 41
NCity   60
St)te   69
Zip 78
Phone   85
```

The above is in Access VBA, but here is the SAME code after a cut + paste into VB.net

[image]

Comment: I converted your code to VB.NET but unfortunately it still did not work for me

Comment: I updated the post with a screen cap of the working vb.net code. The code in VBA or vb.net works just fine for me. And yes, it works for different spacing (kind of thought much why the question was asked).